# How to get time only once in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to save the time when user get registered. This is my table data

```
nic    name    age   time
190    ali      27   2012-04-13 17:31:19
217    bilal    32   2012-04-15 02:00:40
382    hamza    21   2012-04-17 20:59:29
```

I manually created time attribute in MYSQL

```
Column : time
Type TIMESTAMP
Default : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
attributes: on update CURRENT_TIME
```

Now I want to permanent save this time.. When the registered user update his profile the time automatically updated.

Is there any way to not  change the time on update, I just want to save permanently time when user get registered and not to change it on any kind of update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't specify `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  Instead, rely only on the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and omit the column from your `INSERT` statement.

By including the `ON UPDATE` specification, you are forcing the timestamp column to change whenever the row changes.  You don't need that.

```
/* Omit the time column on insert: time will get the default value. */ 
INSERT INTO user (nic, name, age) VALUES ('newuser', 'New user Name', 33);
```